# Populate dataframe from list

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `foo` with 4 empty columns that I need to populate with the contents of list `result`.  I cannot merge by a common id because one does not exist, but `foo` and `result` are of the same length.  How would one access the contents of each element of `result` and convert them into columns of dataframe `foo`?

I understand that to access each part of single list element one would have to write: `result[[1]][1]`, `result[[1]][2]`, `result[[1]][3]`, `result[[1]][4]`, but then how to iterate over them?

I have tried

```
for (i in 1:length(result)){

   foo$coords.x1.min <- result[[i]][1]
}
```

but this only populates the entire column with the first value in the list

```
> nrow(foo)
[1] 103
> length(result)
[1] 103

 > head(foo)
     names            X1            X2            X3            X4
1  4CITIES            NA            NA            NA            NA
2     ACES            NA            NA            NA            NA
3 ADVANCES            NA            NA            NA            NA
4    AMASE            NA            NA            NA            NA
5  ARCHMAT            NA            NA            NA            NA
6      ASC            NA            NA            NA            NA


> head(result)
[[1]]
              min     max
coords.x1 -3.7038 16.3738
coords.x2  5.6761 50.8503

[[2]]
              min     max
coords.x1 -5.4710 25.1442
coords.x2 35.3387 56.4152

[[3]]
              min     max
coords.x1 -9.1393 21.0122
coords.x2 38.7223 57.0488

[[4]]
              min     max
coords.x1  2.1734 22.1567
coords.x2 41.3851 65.5848

[[5]]
              min     max
coords.x1 -7.9093 22.9444
coords.x2 38.5707 41.9028

[[6]]
              min     max
coords.x1  3.0573 24.9384
coords.x2 44.4949 60.1699
```

Comment: is that a `matrix` inside of `result`? it would also be easier if you used `dput` with some values to make it clear.

Comment: the `for` loop should be changed to `foo$coords.x1.min[i] <- result[[i]][1]` otherwise you are telling it to update the entire column

Comment: thanks @manotheshark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this without a loop as well by `unlist`ing the 'result', convert it to a `matrix` with 4 columns, and assign it to the columns of 'foo' except the first one

```
foo[-1] <- matrix(unlist(result), ncol=4, byrow = TRUE)
foo
#     names      X1      X2      X3      X4
#1  4CITIES -3.7038  5.6761 16.3738 50.8503
#2     ACES -5.4710 35.3387 25.1442 56.4152
#3 ADVANCES -9.1393 38.7223 21.0122 57.0488
#4    AMASE  2.1734 41.3851 22.1567 65.5848
#5  ARCHMAT -7.9093 38.5707 22.9444 41.9028
#6      ASC  3.0573 44.4949 24.9384 60.1699
```

#### data

```
result <- list(structure(c(-3.7038, 5.6761, 16.3738, 50.8503), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), c("min", "max"
))), structure(c(-5.471, 35.3387, 25.1442, 56.4152), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), c("min", "max"
))), structure(c(-9.1393, 38.7223, 21.0122, 57.0488), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), c("min", "max"
))), structure(c(2.1734, 41.3851, 22.1567, 65.5848), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), c("min", "max"
))), structure(c(-7.9093, 38.5707, 22.9444, 41.9028), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), c("min", "max"
))), structure(c(3.0573, 44.4949, 24.9384, 60.1699), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), c("min", "max"
))))


foo <- structure(list(names = c("4CITIES", "ACES", "ADVANCES", "AMASE", 
"ARCHMAT", "ASC"), X1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("names", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
 for (i in 1:length(result)){

    foo$X1[i] <- result[[i]][1]
    foo$X2[i] <- result[[i]][2]
    foo$X3[i] <- result[[i]][3]
    foo$X4[i] <- result[[i]][4]
 }
```